# Questions on Fraenkel models

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, math-history, axiom-of-choice

Halbeisen on page 172 contains a section entitled "The Second Fraenkel Model". The original paper by Fraenkel containing this model can be found [here](http://archive.org/stream/sitzungsberichte1922preu#page/252/mode/2up). I have several questions regarding this model and $\mathsf{FM}$-models in general.

1. If this 1922 paper by Fraenkel is not the first describing $\mathsf{FM}$-models, can someone please point me to his very fist paper in which he invents the technique? (given that Halbeisen calls it the second model I suppose there must be an earlier paper containing his first model although looking at [this list of publications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Fraenkel#Published_works) it appears to be his first.)
2. In this 1922 paper he writes that for this model construction we can keep the axioms of Zermelo I,II,IV-VII as they are but in Halbeisen on page 168 it is stated that we need to use modified versions of Empty Set and Extensionality. Hence my question 2.a) is: Is this a mistake in Fraenkel's paper? (Unlikely, I would think) and my question 2.b) is: Empty Set is a consequence of all the other axioms hence wouldn't it be enough to just use a modified version of Extensionality?
3. Last but not least the question that is most important to me: What exactly did Fraenkel's 1922 paper prove? The aim of course was to show that $\mathsf{AC}$ is independent of $\mathsf{ZF}$ by constructing a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ in which $\mathsf{AC}$ fails. But the model he constructed is a model of $\mathsf{ZFA}$ and not of $\mathsf{ZF}$ and it seems to be the case that those transfer methods used to embed these Fraenkel models into symmetric models weren't known for another 30 years or so. Hence: what is the relation of $\mathsf{ZFA}$ and $\mathsf{ZF}$? (without using transfer methods)

Comment: I recall asking my model theory professor about permutations, and he said that there's no much model theoretical use in this method (and that it often needs to be defined externally to the model, rather than internally). So I've retagged your question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My question, even though it contains AC, is not actually about AC. I merely used it as an example.

Comment: Feel free to remove that tag. This technique, however, is fundamental to the axiom of choice (and you will rarely find it used elsewhere. The only place I found was the proof that we can violate the axiom of regularity, and even then the technique was somewhat different than the one used to generate models without choice).

Answer (score 7):

Historically the list of axioms known as $\sf ZF$ wasn't written until mid-1920's when von Neumann wrote his Ph.D. dissertation, where he proved the relative consistency of regularity, and defined the ordinals as we know them today, and so on.

Fraenkel's original proofs contained mistakes. I don't know the exact mistake, but I do know that Mostowski found a mistake; Fraenkel rewrote his arguments; Mostowski found further mistakes, and ended up writing the arguments using supports which is very similar to what we know today, Specker was the one putting the finishing touch on the technique. Do note that not once the constructions were done in $\sf ZFC-Reg$, where sets of the form $x=\{x\}$ were used for atoms. (This is why in quite a few places this method is called Fraenkel-Mostowski or even Fraenkel-Mostowski-Specker.)

Lastly, $\sf ZFA$ contains atoms. That's huge. Even more so when we only "disorder" the impure sets. Note that no matter how hard you'll try, you can never form a permutation model in which the real numbers cannot be well-ordered. Because the power of the integers can be well-ordered in permutation models of $\sf ZFA$. But Fraenkel did "prove" (or at least lay foundations for the proof) that the axiom of choice is not provable from the other axioms when we allow atoms, and that *was* a big step. It shows that this axiom is not a consequence of Zermelo's set theory (sans choice itself, of course) if we allow atoms.

The historical overview, including references, by the way, can be found in both Jech's "The Axiom of Choice" and in Halbeisen's book, in the same chapter (the notes section at the end).

Answer (score 4):

Since we are dealing with models of $\sf{ZFA}$, we have to keep those *atoms* in mind.  In particular, atoms have no elements, and so they have the same elements as the empty set.  But they are different from the empty set.  And from each other.  Therefore a *modified* form of Extensionality is needed.  Usually $\sf{ZFA}$ includes a predicate to the effect of $A(x)$ holds iff $x$ is an atom.  So Extensionality should be rephrased

> $( \forall x ) ( \forall y ) ( ( \neg A(x) \wedge \neg A(y) ) \rightarrow ( ( \forall u ) ( u \in x \leftrightarrow u \in y ) \rightarrow x = y ) )$.

To put it into words: any two non-atoms (*i.e.*, sets) which have the same elements are equal.

The Empty Set Axiom is similarly altered to ensure a *set* without elements:

> $( \exists x ) ( \neg A(x) \wedge ( \forall u ) ( u \notin x ) )$.

As to the question of its necessity? This is a bit tricky.

- Note that *unchanged*, the Axiom Schema of Separation applied to some set $X$ and the formula $\varphi (u) \equiv u \neq u$ will yield some object $Y$ with the property that $u \notin Y$ for all $u$.  However by *unchanged* this means that there is no specification that the object $Y$ is itself a set. In particular, the object $Y$ *could* be an atom.
- Note also the following construction:  Given any atom $a$, consider, by the Axiom of Power Set (unchanged) $$\mathcal{P} ( a ) = \{ X : ( \forall u ) ( u \in X \rightarrow u \in a ) \}.$$ Note that $\mathcal{P} ( a )$ contains all atoms, and no nonempty sets.  Then applying an instance of (a slightly expanded) Axiom Schema of Separation, we get the set $$Y = \{ X \in \mathcal{P} ( a ) : \neg A ( X ) \}.$$ Then either $Y$ is empty, or contains the empty set.  In particular, the empty set must exist.  But this construction only works if you allow the predicate $A$ in instance of the Axiom Schema of Separation, which hasn't been explicitly stated by Halbeisen.

After some extra consideration, it appears to me that the way to get the existence of the empty set in $\sf{ZFA}$ making the least number of changes to $\sf{ZF}$ might be to include the (modified) Axiom of Empty Set.  Of course, one could formulate the axioms of $\sf{ZFA}$ by going through all the axiom of $\sf{ZF}$ and ensure that when objects are constructed they are sets, and then the usual method of showing that the empty set exists would go through.

One should note that in Jech's *The Axiom of Choice*, $\sf{ZFA}$ is described as the theory obtained by making the following alterations to $\sf{ZF}$:

- include a unary predicate symbol $A$, and a constant symbol $0$.
- **Axiom of Empty Set.** $\neg ( \exists x ) ( x \in 0 )$.
- **Axiom of Atoms.** $( \forall z ) ( A(z) \leftrightarrow ( z \neq 0 \wedge \neg ( \exists x ) ( x \in z ) ) )$.
- **Axiom of Extensionality.** $( \forall \text{ set } X ) ( \forall \text{ set } Y ) ( ( \forall u ) ( u \in X \leftrightarrow u \in Y ) \leftrightarrow X = Y )$.
- **Axiom of Regularity.** $( \forall \text{ nonempty } S ) ( \exists x \in S ) ( x \cap S = 0 )$.

where

- $( \forall \text{ set } X ) \ldots$ abbreviates $( \forall X ) ( \neg A ( X ) \rightarrow \ldots )$; and
- $( \forall \text{ nonempty } X ) \ldots$ abbreviates $( \forall X ) ( ( \exists x ) ( x \in X ) \rightarrow \ldots )$.

---

What did Fraenkel's paper do?  You're right that it was a weaker result, proving that $\sf{AC}$ is not provable from $\sf{ZFA}$, but it at least hinted at the possibility of Cohen's later result.  And one should see a similarity between the method of permutation models, and symmetric submodels of generic extensions.  Note, also, that any model of $\sf{ZF}$ is a model of $\sf{ZFA}$, with an empty collection of atoms.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question 2.b) is (rephrased) "does ZF with modified Extensionality imply modified Empty Set". I can't decide from the first part of your answer whether the answer is yes or no. Would you mind rephrasing that part? I will take the absence of your mention of my question 1 as meaning that you don't know. And lastly, can one interpret your second part as "in general, models of ZFA (without transferring) are only useful to give hints about ZF"? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MattN.  I was in the middle of four different things when I typed this and perhaps my fingers were faster than my brain.  I'll come back in 30 mins or so when I'll have a bit more time to think.

Comment: No problem at all, take all the time you want. I am not planning to accept one of the other two answers  and I really appreciate that you would edit your answer for me. (Although I vote for you, seeing this little diamond just now was a bit of a shocker for a second : D)

Comment: @Arthur: I heard you type. Unless your *real name* is von Neumann, or someone of a similar caliber, your fingers are faster than your brain.

Comment: I will accept the answer that contains the most information relevant to my questions. As of now this is your answer even though it doesn't address all of them. The most relevant part in this whole thread being your last paragraph which seems to confirm that ZFA is not all *that* useful. While sort of contained in Asaf's "Asafian Monolgue", without reading your paragraph first, the information encoded there would not have been accessible to me. I am not saying that Asaf's answer is bad, nor that I am stupid but merely that Asaf and my brain are incompatible.

Comment: Sadly so as Asaf himself seems to be full of information. (I will certainly look up the references he quotes and answer the first question myself.)

Comment: @Matt: Regarding "... that ZFA is not all *that* useful." we decide what is useful by deciding what we want to do, and seeing if it can be done with it. ZFA is *very* useful because it can be a lot easier to generate counterexamples to universal statements (e.g. "Every set can be linearly ordered") using atoms, and using the JS/Pincus/Hall embedding theorem(s). In the early 1970's there were a lot of papers working with these methods for this exact reason. It is true that if you want to prove something in $\sf ZF$ then it might not be enough, but it's still quite useful for some things.

Comment: (Also, I don't like the term "Asafian monologue". :-P)

Comment: To add on the last change, sometimes it's better to be verbose and *clear*, than to be minimal. Minimality is overrated anyway.

Comment: Arthur, I'm sorry but I forgot to add one of my questions about the paper to the post: Do you happen to know what the angle brackets in the sets on page 254 mean? For example, he writes $\phi (x) = \{ \{\langle x \rangle, \langle o \rangle \} , \dots$ on line 3.

Comment: @MattN. I have no idea. It seems that he wants the set $\{ \{ \langle x \rangle , \langle 0 \rangle \} , \mathfrak{U} x + \{ \langle 0 \rangle \} \}$ to correspond to what we would call the cartiesian prodcut $\{ x \} \times \mathfrak{U}x$ (and even here I am not 100% certain), but I'm completely in the dark about the nuts and bolts.

Comment: Thank you. Then I'll make a new post about it.

Comment: @MattN. Out of curiosity, is the rest of that expression (outside of the $\langle \; \rangle$ stuff) intelligible to you?

Comment: You mean the $\mathfrak U$? I take it to mean union. The little $x$ is either a set or an atom as far as I can tell. The $o$ is used to denote the empty set. The $+$ is also union but the union of two sets, as opposed to union over all sets in a set $x$.

Comment: @MattN. Your interpretation seems more plausible than mine.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a footnote to the other responses. But it *is* interesting that there seems to be a bit of a resurgence of interest in Fraenkel-Mostowski permutation models going on (for a small local example, this year 'Permutation Models for Set Theory' is on the list of essay topics for Part III Maths Tripos).

One source of renewed interest is from computer scientists interested in "capture-avoiding substitution": for some general thoughts, see e.g. [this paper](http://www.aisb.org.uk/convention/aisb08/proc/proceedings/12%20Computing%20and%20Philosophy/10.pdf).

Another recent source is that Randall Holmes's announced proof of the consistency of NF set theory uses FM techniques. Interesting times!

Comment: As a footnote to your footnote: The last paragraph is not surprising. If I recall correctly, Specker used permutation models to prove the relative consistency of NFU.

Comment: Indeed, in some ways not surprising this might be a way to go -- though (it turns out) a very difficult trick to pull off to prove the consistency of NF itself.

Comment: Well, since the proof about NFU it was still open for like half a century, if I'm not mistaken? I heard it's difficult to pull the same stunt on the devil twice in a row. :-)

Comment: Exactly ...  :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The consistency of NFU was proved by Jensen, not Specker, and his proof did not use permutation methods. There is another permutation method which has been applied to relative consistency results with NF, notably by Dana Scott and C. Ward Henson, similar to the method used to show that foundation is independent of the other axioms of ZF; this is not the FM method. There has as far as I know been very little application of FM permutation methods to NF or NFU prior to the proof of Con(NF) that I am working on. --Randall Holmes

Comment: @Randall: Thank you very much for the corrections. I hope to see more of you on this website!